# Select2 loading data via ajax and selecting a default value

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I am trying to pre-select a default value when i use Select2 with AJAX.

First I had the code build up on page-load, but because my database grew to 30.000 records the perfomance has become really bad.
So I tried using AJAX, loading and searching works perfect, but somehow AJAX broke my select function, before I used :

```
$("#remoteDataExample").select2("val", "Option 1");
```

This works without a problem, without AJAX.
But with AJAX this fails, here is an jsfiddle example :

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jeanpaul1994/XMAq2/400/)

For the non-fiddlers here is the code :

```
 $(document).ready(

function () {
    var searchTerm = null;
    // Remote data example
    var remoteDataConfig = {
        placeholder: "Search for an option...",
        minimumInputLength: 3,
        ajax: {
            url: '/echo/json/',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: function (term, page) {
                // Nothing sent to server side. Mock example setup.
                searchTerm = term.toUpperCase();
            },
            results: function (data, page) {
                // Normally server side logic would parse your JSON string from your data returned above then return results here that match your search term. In this case just returning 2 mock options.
                return {
                    results: getMockData()
                };
            }
        },
        formatResult: function (option) {
            return "<div>" + option.desc + "</div>";
        },
        formatSelection: function (option) {
            return option.desc;
        }
    };

    function getMockData() {
        var mockData = [{
            id: 1,
            desc: 'Option 1'
        }, {
            id: 1,
            desc: 'Option 2'
        }];
        var foundOptions = [];

        for (var key in mockData) {
            if (mockData[key].desc.toUpperCase().indexOf(searchTerm) >= 0) {
                foundOptions.push(mockData[key]);
            }
        }

        return foundOptions;
    };

    $("#remoteDataExample").select2(remoteDataConfig);
    });
```

I am not sure where to place the select2 now, I tried placing it before the ajax, after the ajax. but none seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

you can add the following to your options:

```
initSelection: function (element, callback) {
    callback( { id: 1, desc: 'Option 1' } );
}
```

and change:

```
$("#remoteDataExample").select2(remoteDataConfig);
```

to:

```
$("#remoteDataExample").select2(remoteDataConfig).val('Option 1').trigger("change");
```

to select 'Option 1' as default.

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/srajaee/XMAq2/402/)